# How do I disable socket.io cookie named io server-side?

Tags: server, cookie, node-js

I needed to disable the socket.io cookie named io server-side.
I follow the path to file creating the cookie to a file located at
C:\socket.io\examples\chat\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js
Which lines do I need to remove?

Answer (score 4):

Just pass an option to do it:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(client){});
io.listen(3000, {
  cookie: false
});
```

See it in the docs: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1

Answer (score 2):

I removed the lines below and it removed the cookie
line 14 
`//var cookieMod = require('cookie');`
line 47
`//this.cookie = false !== opts.cookie ? (opts.cookie || 'io') : false;`
line 48
`//this.cookiePath = false !== opts.cookiePath ? (opts.cookiePath || '/') : false;`
line 49 
`//this.cookieHttpOnly = false !== opts.cookieHttpOnly;`
line 290 - line 298
  `//if (false !== this.cookie) {
    //transport.on('headers', function (headers) {
      //headers['Set-Cookie'] = cookieMod.serialize(self.cookie, id,
        //{
          //path: self.cookiePath,
          //httpOnly: self.cookiePath ? self.cookieHttpOnly : false
        //});
    //});
  //}`

Comment: While this solution may work, the one offered by João Marcos Lopes should the standard solution and accepted answer.